# Хеш в query параметрах ui-router'a

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

Для задачи хочу реализовать урл в таком виде:

```
https://site.com/tab?file=12345#type
```

где `tab` = вкладка в которой нахожусь, `12345` номер файла что открыт, `#type` имя подвкладки где находится файл.
Если я использую в роутинге `?` соответственно все последующие параметры идут после амперсанты `&`. выходит урл такого вида `https://site.com/tab?file=12345&type=type`. Что логично, конечно. 
К сожалению нигде не смог найти информацию об хеше в урле с квери параметрами. Усложняется это еще тем что хеш здесь не исполняет роль якоря. 
Подскажите, возможен ли в принципе такой урл используя `ui-router`?

Comment: Возможно немного переделать ваш урл на такой `https://site.com/tab/12345/type`. Если такой подойдет, напишите, я дам ответ как сделать.

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, к сожалению такой урл у меня сейчас, нужно перейти как раз на такой не стандартный..

Comment: Вы всегда можете вытащить переданные параметры через `location`. В вашем случае `location.hash//#type` и `location.search //?file=12345`. Придется конечно или в ручную парсить `location.search` или использовать jQuery.

Comment: Кстати, если вы используете `ui-route` версии больше 1.0.0, то ничего парсить не надо. В `$transition$.params()` будет `{#:"type",file:"12345"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Да, такой вариант возможен.
Судя по `url`, `ui-router` работает в режиме `html5mode = true`.

Ничего особенного делать не надо.
У вас есть роутинг

```
 $stateProvider.state({
            name: 'test-hash',
            url: '/tab?file',//задаем параметр
            views: {
                'content@main': {
                    component: 'testComponent'
                }
            }, resolve: {
                pageResolve: ["$transition$", function ($transition$) {
                    console.log$,$transition$.params());// здесь будет объект {#:"type",file:"12345"}
                }]
            }
        });
```

При задании `url` вида *https://site.com/tab?file=12345#type* в консоли будет `{#:"type",file:"12345"}`.

Пример на [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wwUGqdDZj2WBYHNMaiO1?p=preview)

Comment: спасибо за ответ! с парсингом проблем думаю быть не должно, если такая структура урла возмножна. также можно пробовать с помощью $location.hash() доставать параметр. но заминка в другом. когда я делаю такой урл - он меняется как мне нужно, но роутинг тогда ломается..
http://plnkr.co/edit/TjFzkuu1vkptdP9UfqQL?p=preview
если выбрать Hello -> любую вложенную вкладку

Comment: загвоздка еще в том, что если в последнем роуте сделать урл не квери, а обычный, то все работает (но структура урла, уже конечно без ? )
`var filmState = {
    name: 'main.helloMovies.film',
    url: '^/main/:id'
  }`

Comment: Посмотрите, я обновил ответ. Если честно, я немного выпал из контекста вопроса, и вернуться в него не получилось) Посмотрите планкер, это то, что вам нужно?